# Redirect to time out page - AngularJS / Spring

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I build a web web app using jhipster to generate the code. How can I redirect to another page immediately the session on the server has expired?

My web application does not use web.xml file.

I setup session timeout value in application-dev.yml file as follows:

```
#Session timeout in 2 seconds.   
server:
    port: 8080
    session: 
      timeout: 120
```

Comment: Its better to handle in the JSP/JS file. Let say, your session is going to expire in 30 mins. Have a timer which has initial value of 30mins, when the timer becomes zero, redirect the page to login page.
You can use window.location = "login.jsp"

Comment: I am not using JSPs. My application is a single page applicaton using angularJS and java for backend REST calls

Comment: Even in JS, you can use timer. Just read about setTimeOut and setTimeInterval functions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when session expires on server, next request to server api will return a 401 http error which will be intercepted (see `auth-expired.interceptor.js`)  by the angular app to redirect user to login state.

So either you do something in the interceptor based on some state variable you stored in the angular app or as Azim suggested you start a timer in angular app upon authentication and you manage its timeout in the angular part.